# How do I use PCL from ROS Hydro?

Tags: pcl, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to understand how PCL is integrated into ROS Hydro. I installed ROS in Ubuntu 12.04 using the ros-hydro-desktop-full package. From "rospack list" I can see that it comes with 4 PCL packages:

1. pcl
2. pcl_conversions
3. pcl_msgs
4. pcl_ros

What is the functionality of these 4 packages, especially pcl_ros and pcl? There is also a pcl-1.7 folder in my /opt/ros/hydro/share folder with some cmake config files. There is no package.xml file though. What does this folder do?

Also, I seem to have 2 copies of the pcl-1.7 libraries. I have it in /usr/lib and also in /opt/ros/hydro/lib. So it seems like I have a standalone pcl library (I am not sure how I got this) and one that is integrated with ROS. Is this going to be a problem?

Finally, and this is the biggest source of my confusion, the wiki page for hydro/migration says:

> pcl is no longer packaged by the ROS community as a catkin package, so any packages which directly depend on pcl should instead use the new rosdep rules libpcl-all and libpcl-all-dev and follow the PCL developer's guidelines for using PCL in your CMake.

So, why is there a pcl package in ROS Hydro in the first place with libraries in /opt/ros/hydro/lib?

As you can see I am quite confused, any help will be greatly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78651/how-do-i-use-pcl-from-ros-hydro?/) by [munnveed](https://answers.ros.org/users/6052/munnveed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2013-09-11

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The question was answered in the PCL Users mailing list.

http://www.pcl-users.org/How-do-I-use-PCL-from-ROS-Hydro-td4029613.html

---

Originally posted by [munnveed](https://answers.ros.org/users/6052/munnveed/) with karma: 77 on 2013-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-09-15**:
If possible, please enumerate the exact steps needed for this. I was following the tutorial : http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials, but was not able to run it. While creating package I needed to remove pcl dependency, then also I was not able to compile code using voxel_grid.

**Comment by [munnveed](https://answers.ros.org/users/6052/munnveed/) on 2013-09-15**:
Can specify exactly what error you are getting? And are you using ROS Hydro?

**Comment by [ndepalma](https://answers.ros.org/users/4811/ndepalma/) on 2013-09-24**:
I'm confirming that the tutorials should be updated.

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-10-12**:
Hi, I was able to run it, and pointed out the changes at : http://answers.ros.org/question/90176/running-pcl-in-hydro/ kindly let me know if some correction needs to be done.

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2013-11-03**:
Did you happen to update the tutorial or should I follow the changes on the above link you just put?

**Comment by [aknirala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1931/aknirala/) on 2013-11-03**:
I have updated the tutorial (quite sometime), you can find comments in tutorial saying for hydro users kindly use... Let me know if things are fine.